# How to fetch Google+ friends in Android

Tags: android, google-plus

Through [this example](https://github.com/imellon/Google-Plus-Android-Sample) I am able to integrate Google+ with android and to fetch my information like user id, url, profile name and profile picture.
I want also to fetch  the list of all my friends and to show it.
How can I do this and which class is useful?

Answer (score 6):

This can be done using google plus api. Though you can not get full profile information of every friend in one request, it will give you at least following information

- id
- displayName
- image
- objectType
- url

To get profile information further you have to fetch each friend's profile information separately.

Given below is the code to fetch friends list

```
       mPlusClient.loadPeople(new OnPeopleLoadedListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onPeopleLoaded(ConnectionResult status, PersonBuffer personBuffer, String nextPageToken)
            {

                if ( ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status.getErrorCode() )
                {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Fetched the list of friends");
                    for ( Person p : personBuffer )
                    {
                        Log.v(TAG, p.getDisplayName());
                    }
                }
            }
        }, Person.Collection.VISIBLE); // VISIBLE=0
    }
```

"for-loop" in the callback is there to iterate over each "Person" object.

Now to get further profile information you can use following snippet of code

```
     mPlusClient.loadPerson(new OnPersonLoadedListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onPersonLoaded(ConnectionResult status, Person person)
            {
                if ( ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status.getErrorCode()) 
                {
                    Log.v(TAG, person.toString());
                }

            }
        }, "me"); // Instead of "me" use id of the user whose profile information you are willing to get.
```

For further clarity please take a look at this link
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people

Answer (score 1):

There is not currently an API method exposed to list friends of a G+ user.

You can learn more about what methods are exposed here: https://developers.google.com/+/api/

Comment: @ArpitGarg It is still not listed in the API methods at https://developers.google.com/+/api/ so no, this is still not possible.