# How to get Friend list from Google + login?

Tags: android, google-plus-signin

I have tried many solutions but not getting exact solution for, how to get Google circle peolpe in my app.

using Google People Api. If you have tried provide a code or links here.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584822/how-to-fetch-google-friends-in-android

Comment: @sasikumar i tried not working.